# How to capture the children elements

Tags: javascript, html

I use a event mouse.click to capture a element. But I can't capture then children element.

This is the code injected.

```
document.addEventListener('click', function (event)
{
    let elem = event.target;
    //const elem1 = event.target.closest("a");
    let jsonObject =
    {
        Key: 'click',
        Value: elem.parentElement.id || "Unkown",
        Value1: elem.id || elem.name || elem.value || elem.href || elem.className || "Unkown",
        Value2: elem.outerHTML || "Unkown",
        Value3: elem.innerHTML || "Unkown",
        
    };
   
    window.chrome.webview.postMessage(jsonObject);
         
});
```

I have a multiple choices, but only the elem.outerHTML return something.

This is example : in red the capture with elem.outerHTML.
In yellow that is i would like to capture.

[image]

But I don't know how to capture it.
can someone help me ?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: That looks like it should be working, are you sure your child elements are catching the event? There are a few ways it could avoid them and hit the parent directly without bubbling.

Comment: No, I don't sure. My question is : How capture the  span class ="custom-truncate uiOutputText". My event.click (elem.outerhtml) stoppe at :"One-record-home-flexipage2..."

Comment: Using `event.target` should work. The problem is probably not in the code you have included. See this basic example: https://jsfiddle.net/fks0qr5v/

Comment: I think that the html code is not accessible. I saw that the elements are not keybord focusable. So, I don't any solution. is it possible to deactivate this protection ?